# One alert at a time

Tags: javascript, function, popup, alert

I'm making a form and have a bunch of functions in the form to validate certain fields but the issue I'm having is that when you submit for every validation that returns false an alert will pop up so it ends up being a lot of alerts.

Is there a way to change the call to the functions or the functions themselves so that only one alert would pop up at a time?

My form currently works such that if you submit a form and have left the first name and last name field empty and both fields are compulsory two alerts will pop up saying you have not filled out first name and you have not filled out last name (which can get annoying with the amount of fields I have).

I'm trying to figure out a way so that if you submit the form and have left both fields empty only one alert will pop up saying you have not filled out first name and then after which when you fill out the first name field and have still left the last name field empty then an alert will pop saying you have not filled out last name.

Here is the main block of validation functions I have:

```
function validateText() 
{
var firstname=document.getElementById('txtfirstname');
var familyname=document.getElementById('txtfamilyname');
var streetaddress=document.getElementById('txtaddress');
var suburb=document.getElementById('txtsuburb');
var postcode=document.getElementById('txtpostcode');
var country=document.getElementById('txtcountry');
var telephone=document.getElementById('txttelephone');
var email=document.getElementById('txtemail');
var regodate=document.getElementById('txtregodate');
var regocost=document.getElementById('txtregocost');

if (firstname.value=="")
{
     alert("First name must be filled out");
     return false;
}
if (familyname.value=="")
{
     alert("Family name must be filled out");
     return false;
}

var institutioncompany=document.getElementById('txtinstcomp').value;
if (institutioncompany == "") 
{
     alert("Institution/company must be filled out");
     return false;
}
var category=document.getElementById('category').value;
if (category == "UWS Student" || category == "Other UWS Staff" || category == "UWS Academic")
{
    if (document.getElementById("txtnumber").value == "")
    {
        alert('Student number/Staff number is mandatory');
        return;
    }
}

if (streetaddress.value=="")
{
     alert("Street address must be filled out");
     return false;
}
 if (suburb.value=="")
{
     alert("Suburb must be filled out");
     return false;
}
 if (postcode.value=="")
{
     alert("Postcode must be filled out");
     return false;
}
 if (country.value=="")
{
     alert("Country must be filled out");
     return false;
}
 if (telephone.value=="")
{
     alert("Telephone number must be filled out");
     return false;
}
 if (email.value=="")
{
     alert("Email address must be filled out");
     return false;
}
 if (regodate.value=="")
{
     alert("Date of registration must be filled out");
     return false;
}
 if (regocost.value=="")
{
     alert("Cost of registration must be filled out");
     return false;
}
}


function validateCheckBoxes(theForm) 
{
if (
theForm.checkbox.checked == false &&
theForm.checkbox1.checked == false &&
theForm.checkbox2.checked == false)
{
    alert ('You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes');
    return false;
} else {    
    return true;
}
}

function validateRadioButton() 
{
var radios = document.getElementsByName('yesno');

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) 
{
    if (radios[i].checked) 
{
    return true; //checked
}
};
// not checked, show error
alert ('You didn\'t choose whether you wanted a copy of work proceedings');
return false;
}


function validateEmail() 
{
var emailID = document.rego.email.value;
atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos < 1 || (dotpos - atpos < 2 ))
{
    alert("Please enter correct email ID");
    return false;
}
return(true);
}
```

Here is the way I call some of the functions:

```
<form name="rego" action="submit.htm" onsubmit="return !!(validateText() & validateCheckBoxes(this) & validateRadioButton() & validateEmail() & populateInstitution());" method="POST">
```

Comment: You do not return false everywhere you alert and you want &&, not &

Comment: oh it was that simple, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

& means bitwise AND in javaScript && is logical AND so

```
   !!(validateText() 
    & validateCheckBoxes(this) 
    & validateRadioButton() 
    & validateEmail() 
    & populateInstitution())
```

Will cause evaluation of each function and bitwise and operation of all results.

When you do it like this:

```
   !!(validateText() 
    && validateCheckBoxes(this) 
    && validateRadioButton() 
    && validateEmail() 
    && populateInstitution())
```

The first function returning false will end the evaluation because False AND(logical) anything else will end up as false... This is an internal optimization of javaScript and therefore the functions following the first one returning false will not be evaluated in other words called...

Answer (score 0):

So I was interrupted before I could post my comment as an answer.

Here is what I would consider if I would not want jQuery validation.

The key issue is trying to be consistent. You need to return true and false everywhere

Form:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)"...>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validate(theForm)  {
  return validateText() &&
         validateCategory(document.getElementById("txtcategory")) &&
         validateCheckBoxes(theForm) &&
         validateEmail(theForm);

}

function validateCategory(category) {
  var val = category.value;
  if (document.getElementById("txtnumber").value == "" && (val == "UWS Student" || val == "Other UWS Staff" || val == "UWS Academic")) {
    alert('Student number/Staff number is mandatory');
    document.getElementById("txtnumber").focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var mandatory = {
 firstname: "First name must be filled out",
 familyname: "Family name must be filled out",
 instcomp : "Institution/company must be filled out",
 streetaddress: "Street address must be filled out",
 suburb: "Suburb must be filled out",
 postcode: "Postcode must be filled out",
 country:"Country must be filled out",
 telephone: "Telephone number must be filled out",
 email:"Email address must be filled out",
 regodate:"Date of registration must be filled out",
 regocost:"Cost of registration must be filled out"
}; // note no comma after the last

function validateText() {
  for (var o in mandatory) {
    var fld = document.getElementById("txt"+o);
    if (fld.value==="") {
      alert(mandatory[o]);
      fld.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
function validateCheckBoxes(theForm) {
  if (theForm.checkbox.checked && theForm.checkbox1.checked && theForm.checkbox2.checked) return true;
  alert ('You didn\'t choose any of the checkboxes');
  return false;
}

function validateRadioButton() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName('yesno');
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  if (radios[i].checked) {
    return true; //checked
  }
}
// not checked, show error
  alert ('You didn\'t choose whether you wanted a copy of work proceedings');
  return false;
}
function validateEmail(theForm)  {
  var email = theForm.email;
  var emailID = email.value;
  atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
  dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 1 || (dotpos - atpos < 2 )) {
    alert("Please enter correct email ID");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```